# Border inside of div get hidden by content

Tags: html, border, z-index, jsfiddle

Not sure if the title explains it properly.
I've made a fiddle of my problem: [Fiddle](http://bit.ly/12gGspM)
.
The right box properly shows the border on hover. But when theres content in the box it's hidden. Is there a way I can make the border stay on top?

EDIT: FIXED IT WITH CSS: overflow:hidden;

Comment: make your box wider. The border is supposed to be outside of the content, so the inside of your box should be the size of your content (image)

Comment: That is what I DON'T want. The border is supposed to be inside. Thats the whole challenge mate.

Comment: well, that's not a challenge, that's just not possible then. You can achieve the same result of course, but not using that border property .

Comment: I just did it. So yeah. With that exact border property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image is rendered on top of the box which is covering up the animation. If you take the image out you'll see that the hover functionality works on both boxes.

You probably need to add some CSS for the image instead of just the div that the image is in.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help me much, as I'm not sure what to add.

Comment: Anything that will make it the size of the inner div, not the whole size of the div + border... or cfr my comment you just need to achieve the same effect another way.

Comment: Added another DIV on top of the whole bunch, fixed it.